# Permission denied: AH00649: could not open transfer log file

Tags: centos, permissions, apache-2.4, centos7, apache2

I've set up a new CentOS 7 + Apache 2.4 server on Google Compute and having some troubles getting my Virtual Hosts configured and working. I was previously on CentOS 6 + 2.2 Apache server.

The `CustomLog` line below is what causes Apache to throw the error and refuse to start. In other words, if I comment out that line, Apache starts up fine and serves the files in my `DocumentRoot`.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bethesparkle.com
    ServerAlias www.bethesparkle.com
    <Directory /var/www/users/kenny/domains/bethesparkle.com/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI Includes
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/users/kenny/domains/bethesparkle.com/html
    CustomLog /var/www/users/kenny/domains/bethesparkle.com/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is what shows up in the error log when I try to start Apache:

```
[log_config:error] [pid 27405] (13)Permission denied: AH00649: could not open transfer log file /var/www/users/kenny/domains/bethesparkle.com/logs/access.log.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I've been using linux and unix for years, but I'm new to SELinux, FYI. Here is the output of `ls -Zd` for each directory leading up to the logs dir:

```
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0       /var
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www
drwxr-xr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/users
drwxr-xr-x. kenny apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/users/kenny
drwxr-xr-x. kenny apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/users/kenny/domains
drwxr-xr-x. kenny apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/users/kenny/domains/bethesparkle.com
drwxrwxr-x. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 /var/www/users/kenny/domains/bethesparkle.com/logs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You apparently missed my advice to you on this, in your last question: Put the log files back in their standard location.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I totally did miss that, sorry about that. I'll move them over there since I'm the only one who ever deals with those logs. If I wanted them outside of the the /var/log/httpd directory though, would that also require an SELinux command to allow it?